# how to group_concat rows with clickable links id

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

Output:

```
//HotelID   //HotelName   //Operators 1,2,3

1    -       Nila    -    CleanX,Vey,Leo
```

I want the operators to be individual clickable links , asigned to their IDs.

With GROUP_CONCAT they're all combine into one ID. I used LEFT JOIN in MYSQL

I Want it this way "this is just an example.Code wise it wont work"

Every id will be a link to click

```
//HotelID //HotelName //Operators 1,2,3
1    -     Nila   -  CleanX id1, Vey id2, Leo id3
```

Instead of all GROUP_CONCAT to one ID.

Is there a way since operators are GROUP_CONCAT in Mysql query to prevent duplication when echoed out.

Is there a way maybe to just GROUP but not GROUP_CONCAT Help please.

Comment: Can you share an example of a query that produces the current output?

Comment: table schema and sample data as well.

Comment: Clickable links is not something that MySQL can do

Comment: $vtest=mysql_query("SELECT hotels.hotelID, hotels.hotelName,operators.opID, GROUP_CONCAT( operators.opID,operators.opName) AS opName
FROM hotels
LEFT JOIN operators
ON operators.opHotelID=hotels.hotelID
GROUP BY(hotels.hotelID)");

Comment: @strawberry how can i make the the GROUP_CONCAT columns clickable than if they are 3 but are combine. But i want them to have all IDs

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to PHP? Generally, issues of data display are best handled in application code. And, to a rough approximation, there is no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT (or CONCAT) is the solution. These functions seem to me to be the antithesis of what SQL is all about.

Comment: @Strawberry yes is php. i want the combine rows to be clickable links because with group_concat the 3rows with the same id are combine as one id but i want them not to be combine as one id but just to be combine and having their ids e.g hotel1 , hotel2, hotel3 with unique ids 1-3.

Comment: @Mureinik $x_hotel=mysql_query("SELECT hotels.hotelID, hotels.hotelName,operators.opID, GROUP_CONCAT( operators.opID,operators.opName) AS opName
FROM hotels
LEFT JOIN operators
ON operators.opHotelID=hotels.hotelID
GROUP BY(hotels.hotelID)");

$x_num=mysql_numrows($vtest);
while($bow= mysql_fetch_array($vtest)) { 
echo" 
<br><a  href='index.php?id=$bow[hotelID]'><img src='./pics/$bow[1]' style='margin-top:0px; margin-left:-390px; max-width:60px; max-height:60px;'></a></br>
<br><a  href='index.php?id=$bow[opID]'>$bow[opName]</a></br>

";

Comment: @Mureinik copy the code into an editor, reading it in the comments its rough

Comment: @Strawberry $x_hotel=mysql_query("SELECT hotels.hotelID, hotels.hotelName,operators.opID, GROUP_CONCAT( operators.opID,operators.opName) AS opName FROM hotels LEFT JOIN operators ON operators.opHotelID=hotels.hotelID GROUP BY(hotels.hotelID)"); $x_num=mysql_numrows($vtest); while($bow= mysql_fetch_array($vtest)) { echo" <br><a href='index.php?id=$bow[hotelID]'><img src='./pics/$bow[1]' style='margin-top:0px; margin-left:-390px; max-width:60px; max-height:60px;'></a></br> <br><a href='index.php?id=$bow[opID]'>$bow[opName]</a></br> ";

Comment: @Mureinik 
-----hotels-----First table
hotelID
hotelName       // i used pics for it 3


----operators-----Second table

opID
opName
opServices
opHotelID

Comment: @Strawberry 
-----hotels-----First table
hotelID
hotelName       // i used pics for it 3


----operators-----Second table

opID
opName
opServices
opHotelID

Comment: @Nathan Long help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293220/how-to-group-concat-rows-with-clickable-links-id?noredirect=1#comment48683135_30293220

Answer (score 0):

Just use this query. The rest of your problem is about data display and user interface, all of which is best handled in application-level code (e.g. PHP).

```
SELECT h.hotelID
     , h.hotelName 
     , o.opID
     , o.opName
  FROM hotels h
  LEFT 
  JOIN operators o
    ON o.opHotelID = h.hotelID 
 ORDER 
    BY h.hotelID
     , o.opID;
```

Comment: i got it now my problem is just to display comments in a popup overlay.